# how to initiate a class from variable CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How would one initiate a class from a variable in CoffeScript? in another words:

```
className = 'Domain'
domain = new className()

should.exist(domain)
'Domain'.should.equal(domain.constructor.name)
```

How would the line two should look like to satisfy the assertions? Thank You

Edit:
The class is declared as following

```
class Domain
  constructor: (obj) ->
    for own key, value of obj
      @[key] = value

  save: (fn) ->
    self = @
 ...
module.exports = Domain
```

Peter Lyons answer works with a little adjustments to the way our class defined. In short, the solution:

```
DomainClass = require('./index')
newDomain = new DomainClass({...})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to lookup the class name using square brackets in the correct scope. In a browser, you could do `new window[className]` or in node if your class was in a module you could do `new require('./models')[className]`.

Comment: The node version doesn't seem to be working. The error getting is 'TypeError: Object function Domain(obj) {
      var key, value;

      for (key in obj) {
        if (!__hasProp.call(obj, key)) continue;
        value = obj[key];
        this[key] = value;
      }
    } has no method 'Domain'

Comment: What worked: DomainClass = require('./model') newLine
          newDomain = new DomainClass({..})